# Integrity constraint exception handling with user friendly message Yii2

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with a triple key, now I want to show a "friendly" warning if I repeat the key combination instead of this:

> Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'CP MEIJ 01/15-2' for key 'PRIMARY' The SQL being executed was: INSERT
>   INTO `modelo03` (`planificacion_fk`, `cargo_fk`, `medida_apl_fk`,
>   `modelo03_cant`, `dic_fk`) VALUES ('CP MEIJ 01/15', 3, 2, 4, 'SA')
>
> Error Info: Array (
>       [0] => 23000
>       [1] => 1062
>       [2] => Duplicate entry 'CP MEIJ 01/15-2' for key 'PRIMARY' )
>
> ↵
>
> Caused by: PDOException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>    violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'CP MEIJ 01/15-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
>
> in C:\wamp\www\prueba_protected\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php at
>    line 768

as would be the way to achieve this? sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop inserting same `planificacion_fk` for new entries. The error says, you are inserting a same primary key value which must be unique for all entries.

Comment: I know what is the error, but i want show i nice warning, no that screen

Comment: Hi ernesto have you find the way to pick up the mysql errors?

Comment: 'deleteOptions'=>['title'=>'your tooltip', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'data-confirm'=>'your text'],

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html)(`ActiveRecord` is subclass of the `Model` class) to insert this data to the database, you can use [UniqueValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html).

In this case model will not be saved, and you can get list of errors using `$model->errors`.

You can configure validator to use you own error message.